# How can I use my own data set in sklearn - Python3

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to do a linear regression, but I want to use my own data from some `.txt` file.
I have some data with a table with 3 columns.

Then, I would like to know how can I change this following code, that is an example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

Then I changed a bit the code in the example before and I invented some data, is that a correct way to do it? Like use some `X` and `Y` like this way. And then I would also to know how in the equation: `x_train = x [:2]`, the `[:2]` has some influence on my procedure. I didn't really get this part.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

#X has to be numpy array not list.

x=([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
y=[5,3,8,3,4,5,5,7,8,9,10]

x_train = x [:2]
x_test = x [2:]

y_train = y[:2]
y_test = y[2:]

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit (x_train,y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)

#coefficient
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

#the mean square error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Variance score: %.2f' % r2_score(y_test, y_pred))

plt.scatter(x_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.axis([0, 20, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

**EDIT 1**

With the help I received in this webpage, I tried to make some code, to produce a fit of my own data, but I'm not able to get the correct fit, so if someone has time to help me a bit more or tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

The code I'm using with the pics I'm getting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
#x = data[['col1','col2']]
x = data[['col1']]
y = data['col3']

#convert to array to fit the model
x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)

# define the KFolds 
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)

#define the model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# use cross validation and return the r2 score for each Fold 
#if you want to return other scores than r2, just change the scoring in cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(regr, x, y, cv= kf, scoring= 'r2')

print(scores)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
  print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
  X_train, X_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
  y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]


plt.scatter (X_test, y_test)
plt.show()
```

I'm here putting a picture of what looks like my data and what I get from TRAIN AND TEST[image: First part of the code]

Then I did some fit procedure, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
regr.fit (X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

And I get a completely strange fit.[image: Fit of my function]

I don't understand why I get it, if when i did this using MINUIT, my fit worked. So, if someone has some hints to help me.

Why apparently the program is not using my data from "y" to do TRAIN or TEST samples?

My data can be taked here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nbbsc0fqznkwxvt/AAD-u6lM4orJOGrgIyz0o8B9a?dl=0

For me the only important is col1 and col3, the col2 should be ignored. Then I want make a fit in this data and extract the value of my fit. I know it's a line that fits this data.

Comment: This is too broad and just showing other's code without own attempts. Read the docs to understand the data-shapes needed. Verify this by printing out ```diabetes_X.shape``` and co. Then read numpy or pandas docs to learn about reading data into numpy arrays / data frames. (it depends on your txt-file which is not given; further more your description about that file is informal)

Comment: @sascha I've been looking on internet for that. I could not find some explanation to understand how to use my own data in a linear regression. All examples are using some dataset that is not from the own person. I can't provide my datasets here. It's not public information. I just have a txt file with 3 columns about some measurements. You can offer some link where I can find some explanation about how to upload my own dataset. Your answer is not helpful at all. But anyway thank you!

Comment: **Everything you need** is covered in the docs! sklearn's for the shapes needed. Then you only need to create arrays with the right shapes. How you do it does not matter. numpy and pandas both provide readers. Be prepared to see this question get closed if you don't provide helpful info (the given answer mentions an approach)! (there are infinite many different encodings of text-based 3-column datasets!)

Comment: @Gabriela the main reason that you want a part of the data to train the model and another part to evaluate it, is just because usually people do this to avoid overfitting. Your model will learn some data and then you will evaluate this model using new UNSEEN data. The train_test_split function here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html is uded to split arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets. Alos, how many samples (rows) do you have in your txt file?

Comment: @sera I have 30 lines in my data. I didn't get how to choose this interval to read my data. Like the interval to learn is different to the interval to test. Like, in my example I don't get if I can have all, for example, [:2] or not... this still a bit unclear for me, since I have started this couple of days ago. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gabriela the amount of data that usually people use if 70% of the data for training and 30% for testing. Also, there are other ways to split the data. To name some, KFold splitting, Leave one out (LOO) cross validation etc. The best way to evaluate the model and avoid overfitting is by using cross validation (Kfolds, leave one out etc). I can post an example if you think it could help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the main reason that you want to split the data and use a part of the data to train the model and another part to evaluate it, is to avoid overfitting. Usually, we use **KFolds** or **LOO**(leave one out) to perform cross validation.

**Here is an example using 30 samples, 3 variables and cross validation with KFolds.**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import linear_model

#create artificial data with 30 lines (samples) and 3 columns (variables)
x = np.random.rand(30,3)

#create the target variable y
y = range(30)

# convert the list to numpy array (this is needed for fit method of sklearn)
y = np.asarray(y)

# define the KFolds (3 folds in this example)
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

#define the model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# use cross validation and return the r2 score for each Fold (here we have 3). 
#if you want to return other scores than r2, just change the scoring in cross_val_score.
scores = cross_val_score(regr, x, y, cv= kf, scoring= 'r2')

print(scores)
```

Results:

**Here you can see the r2 score of the model for each fold.** So we splitted the data 3 times and we used 3 different training data to get these values. This is done automatically by sklearn inside cross_val_score method.

```
 array([-30.36184326,  -0.4149778 , -28.89110233])
```

**To understand what KFold does you can print the training and testing indices using:**

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

**Results**:

```
('TRAIN:', array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
   27, 28, 29]), 'TEST:', array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
('TRAIN:', array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
   27, 28, 29]), 'TEST:', array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]))
('TRAIN:', array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19]), 'TEST:', array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]))
```

Now, you can see that for the 1st Fold we used the samples: `10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29.`

Next, for the second fold we used the samples: `0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29.`

**Note**: these numbers are the indices of the x data. E.g. 2 means the 3rd sample(line). In python we count from 0.
As you can see, we do not use the exact same data (samples) in each Fold.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 1**

To answer your question about loading the txt data. Let's suppose that you have a txt file with 3 columns. The first 2 columns are the features and the last column is the y (target).

In this case, you can do the following using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
x = data[['col1','col2']]
y = data['col3']

#convert to array to fit the model
x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)
```

The txt is here: https://ufile.io/eb5xl (choose slow download).

**EDIT 2**

**This is only for visualization purposes**. I do not split the data. I use all the data to fit the model and then I predict on the same data. Then I plot the predicted values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')

x = data[['col1']]
y = data['col3']

#convert to array to fit the model
x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)

y_predicted = regr.predict(x)

plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, y_predicted, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

**Results**:

It seems that the data dont follow a linear pattern. Other models should be used (e.g. **exponential fitting**)

[image: Linear regression]

Comment: thanks very much for your explanation. This helped a lot. But still I have some questions. Sorry if they are to basic, but I'm studying by my own this topic. Anyway my questions are: the difference between your code and the one i posted was that in your code seems that the computer does alone the separation between the trainings and test? Because in my code we should write the interval we want to do it. In your example is KFOLD is that correct? Also, I would like to know if I can write in the x, for example a matrix with 30 lines and 3 columns with my data?

Comment: And final question, is that possible in the method linear regression also define the error that I have in my variable to do the fit? Because I have my own error, so if I inform this to the code, can the fit be more precise? I hope my questions are clear. If not I can rewrite. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gabriela for the first question: yes the main difference is that in my code I use KFold to split the data. for the second question: yes it is very easy. just tell me what data do you have. csv file or excel or txt ? for the last question:the model calculates the error, i guess it should be the same as the one that you have. If you want to use your error and feed it to the model, then you have to hard-code a linear regression function on your own.

Comment: I see, because normally I use MINUIT for do some fit and then I can use my own error. But I will try use my data for this model and see whats happens. I have .txt data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: is suposed to me get [ 0.  1.  0.]?

Comment: yes, if you use the data that I uploaded and the code that I posted the results is 0,1,0. This is just an example. In general, more info about the r2 can be found here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

Comment: thanks for your help! Was just to check that I did all correctly, because I also dowloaded now pandas. My final question, sorry for that, it's if I import "from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score", can I see also in this method the coefficient, like in my example "regr.coef_", mean square error, because the r2 score we already have. That's it!! Really, really t hanks!

Comment: no you cannot. you can use this command: r2_score(y_true, y_pred) to only get the r2 score of the model based on the true and the predicted values. This function does not have .coef_ attribute. Make sure to read the documentation of each function. This way you will be able to know the attributes of all the functions that you use. Glad that I helped

Comment: I have edited my question, showing what I did in my code.

Comment: you dont plot the right things. also when you use scores =... you fit the model. Then you fit it again using: regr.fit (X_train, y_train). Add the data.txt file and make clear what you need ( the plot of the regression on the predicted values ?)

Comment: I have updated my data.

Answer (score 1):

Turn you text file in a `CSV`, that is, a text file with this structure :

```
col1name;col2name;col3name
1;0;2
4;6;8
0;1;3
```

Then, put your dataset in a `pandas.DataFrame`, use all columns but the last one as your X dataset, and the last one as your Y.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

file_path = "path/to/your/file.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = file_path, sep = ";")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.loc[:, data.columns != "name_of_your_last_column"], data.loc[:, data.columns == "name_of_your_last_column"], test_size = 0.25)

classifier = LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Train set score :", classifier.score(X_train, y_train)
print("Test set score :", classifier.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Please note that this is a minimal example, you should be using a cross validation procedure to avoid overfitting, and a grid search procedure to avoid underfitting.

Comment: Thanks for your information! I will read for sure the way how to ask questions. I have changed my question a bit based in the things I was trying. I would like to know also if the way I did is wrong or not? I started yesterday with Python3 and sklearn. So, I think for implement your example I will need just a bit more of time to understand. Thank you very much! I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Gabriela please show your appreciation in practice, by accepting and/or upvoting useful answers (which take up precious time for respondents)